# Minimize "new Email" Dialog

Tags: c#, outlook

I try to modify a new email. 
Everything works fine but i want to minimize the "new Email" Dialog in Outlook during the modification and i don't know where to do this.

This is my code so far:

```
public Outlook.MailItem convertMail()
{                 
    mail.Subject = "New subject";
    mail.Body =  "This is the test text";        
    return mail;
}
```

I already tried:

```
mail.Display(false);
```

This doesnt work and i don't know which function to use.
How can i minimize the Outlook Dialog by code?

Comment: May not be able to do it from the API, but if you can find the handle to the window, you could leverage Windows APIs to control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Outlook Interop I believe the nearest you could get is:

```
outlookApp.Inspector inspect;
inspect = mail.GetInspector;
inspect.Display;
inspect.WindowState = olMinimized; // probably outlookApp.olMinimized
```

(although I cannot test currently)

Comment: same here, it [should be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olwindowstate.aspx) `olMinimized` :)

Comment: Such americaniz(s)ms!

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. It works perfect. Both answers are identical but i can only choose one right answer. You were the first one who answered so i set it here :(

Answer (score 3):

The window state of the message composer is not a property of the mail item, but of its inspector:

```
var inspector = mail.GetInspector;
inspector.WindowState = OlWindowState.olMinimized;
```

This assumes that the window is already shown on screen by the time this code executes. Otherwise, call `inspector.Display(false)` before you set the window state.